# Elementary motion

Tags: kinematics

A lorry is travelling at $60km/h$ when the brakes are applied. Assuming that the deceleration is uniform, how far has the lorry travelled when its speed is $36km/h$ after $6$seconds.

**What I did:**

$s =\frac{(v+u)}2t;$

$s = 80$ $m$

But the answer to the question in the textbook is $40m$. I don't know why this happened.

I tried using the $v/t$ graph but I still arrived at the same answer.

Comment: Are you using negative acceleration?

Comment: @RobertFrost Yes I did. But negativities will eventually cancel out.

Comment: I get the same answer as you.

Comment: This question should be tagged as kinematics not mechanics...

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same answer as you. Either you read it wrong or there's an error in your textbook.

Average speed is $(60+36)/2 km/h=48km/h$

Time is 6 seconds: $t=6/(60\times60) hours=.0017hours$

Distance travelled equals $d=vt=48\times .0017=.08km=80m$